# Reading a text file into 2d array

Tags: c, file, multidimensional-array, scanf

I have a text file with just random letters in rows and columns.  All I would like to do is make a 2d array so that it's `puzzle[i][j]` where if I put `printf("%c", puzzle[5][4]);` it would simply give me the 4th row and 3rd columns character (since it starts at 0 in an array).  Here is my code so far.

```
#define MAXROWS     60
#define MAXCOLS     60
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    FILE *TableFilePtr;
    char TableFileName[100];
    char PuzzleFileName[100];
    char puzzle[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];
    printf("Please enter the table file name: ");
    scanf("%s",TableFileName);

    TableFilePtr=fopen(TableFileName, "r");

    if(TableFilePtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open %s", TableFileName);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char words;
    int n;
    n=0;
    int i,j,row,col;
    int rowcount, colcount;
    printf("\n how many rows and colums are there?  separate by a space: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&row, &col);
    /*  while(fscanf(TableFilePtr,"%c",&words)!= EOF)
    {
        printf("%c",words);
    }
    */

    /*for (colcount=0;colcount<col;colcount++)
    {
        for (rowcount=0;rowcount<row;rowcount++)
        {
            printf("%c ",words);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
    */


    for(i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){
            fscanf(TableFilePtr, "%c %s\n",&puzzle[i]][j]);
                //puzzle[i][j]=words;
    //          printf("%c ", puzzle[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

The commented area at the end (just the starting part) works to simply print out the text file in the compiler.  I would like to get it to be in a 2d array though.

```
for(colcount=0;colcount<col;colcount++){...}
```

Comment: uve mixed up your understanding of array indices, was that a typo?

Comment: Note that `puzzle[5][4]` prints the value in the sixth row and fifth column, not the value in the fourth row and third column — precisely because indexing starts at 0.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this (I didn't use all of your exact variable names but you get the idea):

```
    char puzzle[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS], line[MAXCOLS];
    FILE *infile;
    int cols = 0, rows=0;

    /* ... */

    infile = fopen(TableFileName, "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, infile) != NULL)
    {
        for(cols=0; cols<(strlen(line)-1); ++cols)
        {
            puzzle[rows][cols] = line[cols];
        }
        /* I'd give myself enough room in the 2d array for a NULL char in 
           the last col of every row.  You can check for it later to make sure
           you're not going out of bounds. You could also 
           printf("%s\n", puzzle[row]); to print an entire row */
        puzzle[rows][cols] = '\0';
        ++rows;
    }
```

Edit:  much shorter version will have newline and NULL chars at the end of each row unless you manually pick them off.  You may have to tweak puzzle[][] (use MAXCOLS +/- n or some such) to make it work for you.

```
    for(c=0; c<MAXROWS; ++c){
        fgets(puzzle[rows], sizeof puzzle[rows], infile);
    }
```

At the end of the loop, `puzzle[x][y]` should be a 2d array of chars from your input file.  Hope that helps.

Comment: That's C for array index out of bounds (usually).  Remember that the counting starts at 0 so if you declare `int myArray[10]`, the elements are 0-9.  If you try to access `myArray[10]` you get seg err.

Comment: That's what I meant by `You may have to tweak puzzle[][] (use MAXCOLS +/- n`.