# C language, How to fix the segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, file, segmentation-fault

Here is my code so far

```
#define MAXROWS     60
#define MAXCOLS     60
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


main()
{
char TableFileName[100];
char PuzzleFileName[100];
char puzzle[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];
char line[MAXCOLS];
FILE *TableFilePtr;
int cols;
int rows;
cols=0;
rows=0;
printf("Please enter the table file name: ");
scanf("%s",TableFileName);


/* ... */

TableFilePtr = fopen(TableFileName, "r");
//printf("\n how many rows and colums are there?  separate by a space: ");
 //  scanf("%d %d",&rows, &cols);

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, TableFilePtr) != NULL)
{
    for(cols=0; cols<(strlen(line)-1); ++cols)
    {
        puzzle[rows][cols] = line[cols];
    }
    /* I'd give myself enough room in the 2d array for a NULL char in 
       the last col of every row.  You can check for it later to make sure
       you're not going out of bounds. You could also 
       printf("%s\n", puzzle[row]); to print an entire row */
    puzzle[rows][cols] = '\0';
    ++rows;
}
/*int c;
for(c=0; c<MAXROWS; ++c){
    fgets(puzzle[rows], sizeof puzzle[rows], TableFilePtr);
}*/
printf("%s",puzzle[5][5]);
}
```

what i would like to do is make it so it reads from a text file which contains a wordsearch in a txt file so that it has just random letters.  i would like to be able to make it so that i am able to say puzzle[5][5] and it gives me the character in the 4th row and 4th column.  I am running into a segmentation fault and i do not know how to fix it though.

Comment: do you have a debugger?

Comment: Never declare `main()` in this way. You should always declare it `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, and always `return` an exit code.

Comment: Mitch, I do not have a debugger

Comment: and will that change the results jonathon?

Comment: Post your exact error? What line is the fault on?

Comment: I feel like this question title could be the subtitle of a documentary on the C language.

Comment: I use cygwin terminal for my compiler.  heres my error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"  It would be nice to know the line :(

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: `int main(void)` is also valid, but yeah.

Comment: Update- i changed it so that in the for loop, it is just for(c;...).  i  also changed it to %c in the printf.  but now puzzle[5][5] doesnt work.  any ideas on what to do?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I believe that `int main()` is also correct and most co-founders of the language agree that `()` shouldn't take any number of arguments.

Comment: @phoeagon Yes, you are correct. My point was to not use the "assumed `int`" return type.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print a string with `printf("%s", puzzle[rows][cols])` and giving a `char` `puzzle[rows][cols]` is 1 character and not a string.

do this: `printf("%c", puzzle[rows][cols]);` instead.

Comment: hmm im still getting a segmentation error, their probably is more then one case.  i see what you mean completely with this though.

Answer (score 0):

```
char puzzle[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];
char line[MAXCOLS];
//...
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, TableFilePtr) != NULL)
{
    for(cols=0; cols<(strlen(line)-1); ++cols)
    {
        puzzle[rows][cols] = line[cols];
    }
    puzzle[rows][cols] = '\0';
    ++rows;
}
```

This is dangerous because you never check that the number of lines is less than MAXROWS or that the length of each line is less than MAXCOLS. That means that a malformed data file can cause you to write beyond the bounds of the `puzzle` array, which can cause a segmentation fault, corrupted memory, or other problems.

To fix, you need to include limits in the loop conditions, like this:

```
while (frets(line, sizeof line, TableFilePtr) != NULL && rows < MAXROWS) {
    for (cols=0; cols<(strlen(line)-1) && cols < MAXCOLS; ++cols) {
        //...
```

Comment: Does that mean i change it to    for(cols=0; (cols<(strlen(line)-1)&&rows<MAXROWS); ++cols) ???

Comment: also quick question, what does the line puzzle[rows][cols] = '\0'; mean?

Comment: @Alex Right -- added the fix above. As for the second question... it's your code, right? I assume that you're trying to set the last character in each row to `\0` so that you can read each row as a string.

Comment: not all my code, a bunch of this was from help from another user.  here is the other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561119/c-language-read-text-file-and-put-into-2d-array?answertab=oldest#tab-top.

Comment: @Alex Did you read the comment above that line? It's right there in the code in your question, and it completely explains the `'\0'`.

Comment: the way i see it is that it gets each character one at a time put it into the line[cols] whichs gets put in as puzzle[row][cols] and the row # keeps increasing and the column number changes each character.  not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see obvious errors except you didn't check the boundary of puzzle array when you write chars into it. so I think maybe a possible reason is your input file is too large to fit into puzzle array then the array has been overflowed.